# DhcpInfo.ipAddress integer overflow?

Tags: android, ip, overflow

How exactly does `DhcpInfo.ipAddress` store IP address to integer?

I am connected to a local network with IP 192.168.1.101, getting number 1 694 607 552. When converting this to IP address, getting 101.1.168.192 (reverse order of octets).

What I need is  **long** integer representing the correct, not reversed IP .. so 3 232 235 877 (representing "192.168.1.101") in this case, but I am lost in conversions. How can I achieve this? I need always correct long integer representing the IP, but I am not sure, how it would look like, if my IP address is e.g. 192.168.1.253..

Thanks for help.

// Edit

```
public static String int_to_ip (int ip_address) {

    int octet1 = (ip_address & 0xFF000000) >>> 24;
    int octet2 = (ip_address & 0xFF0000) >>> 16;
    int octet3 = (ip_address & 0xFF00) >>> 8;
    int octet4 = ip_address & 0xFF;

    return new StringBuffer().append(octet1).append('.').append(octet2)
            .append('.').append(octet3).append('.')
            .append(octet4).toString();

}
```

Comment: reversed order of octets indicates an endianness issue, not an overflow. please post the code where you convert the integer value to an IP address

Comment: @samgak Code provided